# Automatically move a specified file to another location

Tags: batch-file, automation, move

I am currently using the following bat code to move my files from one folder to another

```
@echo off
set X=0
set "source=C:\<Source Folder Path>"
set "destination=D:\<Destination Folder Path>"
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /mov /minage:%X%
exit /b
```

However, I would like to move only a specified file within this source folder, rather than everything in this folder. Namely, if the excel file contains ABCXYZ as a prefix (eg file name: ABCXYZ-June2021.xls), it will be moved to my destination folder.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

#### However, I would like to move only a specified file within this source folder

> **Syntax**
>
> `ROBOCOPY Source_folder Destination_folder [files_to_copy] [options]`
>
> **Key**
>
> `file(s)_to_copy` : A list of files or a wildcard. (defaults to copying *.*)

Change your `robocopy` command to:

```
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" ABCXYZ*.xls /mov /minage:%X%
```

See [Robocopy "Robust File Copy" - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) for more information